# How to I get the <td> text OR a link from 'a/href' inside the <td> if the td has a link in it

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

Using **IMPORTXML** in Google Sheets to get the links from a table/td.

Page Source: (Some of the 'td' contains text with no links, whereas some 'td' have links but no text.)

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="/match/cameroon-brazil-2022-12-02">Cameroon - Brazil</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="/match/netherlands-usa-2022-12-03">Netherlands - USA</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Winner Group C vs Australia</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>France vs Runner-up Group C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="/match/england-senegal-2022-12-04">England - Senegal</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Winner Group E vs Runner-up Group F</td>
</tr>
```

```
=IMPORTXML(B3,"//table//tr/td/a/@href")
```

CURRENT OUTPUT : (This extracts all td which has a/href, and omitting which do not have a/href)

```
1. /match/cameroon-brazil-2022-12-02
2. /match/netherlands-usa-2022-12-03
3. /match/england-senegal-2022-12-04
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT: (ignore the numbers (#1 to #6) in the output)

1. Include empty rows (when 'td' doesn't have a/href)

```
1. /match/cameroon-brazil-2022-12-02
2. /match/netherlands-usa-2022-12-03
3. 
4. 
5. /match/england-senegal-2022-12-04
6.
```

2. OR Include 'td' text (when 'td' doesn't have a/href)

```
1. /match/cameroon-brazil-2022-12-02
2. /match/netherlands-usa-2022-12-03
3. Winner Group C vs Australia
4. France vs Runner-up Group C
5. /match/england-senegal-2022-12-04
6. Winner Group E vs Runner-up Group F
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version can be achieved with this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//table/tr/td[not(a)] | //table/tr/td/a/@href
```

It merges the values of `<td>`s which have no `<a>` children with the `href` attributes of the `<td>`s that have one.

It's output is

```
/match/cameroon-brazil-2022-12-02
/match/netherlands-usa-2022-12-03
Winner Group C vs Australia
France vs Runner-up Group C
/match/england-senegal-2022-12-04
Winner Group E vs Runner-up Group F
```